# PixelPerfect и React / Webpack

Tags: reactjs, вёрстка, webpack

PixelPerfect перезапускается(исчезает/появляется) после каждого обновления в коде.

В Gulp такого не было, в webpack или react дело видимо.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим/знает, что можно пробовать, чтобы убрать перезагрузку pixelperfect?