# Webpack dev-server неверно отрабатывает?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

После изменения кода webpack dev-server перезагружает страницу.
В Create-react-app просто идет обновление страницы, без ее перезагрузки.

Так и должно быть? Или можно настроить вебпак, чтобы он обновлял(как cra), а не перезагружал страницу полностью.

Ссылка на webpack config: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-poitras-2cp859?file=/src/index.js

Ссылка на package.json: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-murdock-hzl493?file=/src/index.js

Comment: У меня есть предположения, что это дубликат вашего же [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1529726/pixelperfect-%d0%b8-react-webpack)  приложите в качестве кода конфиг вебпака, чтобы повысить вероятность ответа.

Comment: Ссылка на webpack config: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-poitras-2cp859?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Есть такая опция как `hot` в вашем конфиге я ее не вижу ее можно добавить в скрипте к вызову вебпака `--hot` либо в настройках дев сервера в конфиге вебпака: `hot:true`

Comment: Нет реакции на hot: true и на --hot, но на --hot only уже не перезагружает всю страницу, но страница так и не обновляется. Просто раньше вебпак ее сам перезагружал, а теперь это надо делать руками.

Comment: Добавил файл package.json в описание, если посмотрите, может там что-то не так В любом случае спасибо